# @ResponseMapping(value="???") How do I get a method to save to a repository in Spring Boot with REST?

Tags: rest, servlets, spring-boot

I want to save the PBResponse object using REST.

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json", headers = "Content-Type=application/json")
   @ResponseBody
    public PrintBossResponse getPBResponse() throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {

...


    return PBResponseRepository.save(bpResp);

}
```

It is in the following REST Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPBResponse", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json", headers = "Content-Type=application/json")
public class BillPaymentResponseFromXML {
```

I want it to produce a PBResponse JSON object for the view to use and display.  I have the data and the view is ready.  All I need is to get this object to save.

I get an illegal state exception now.

Stacktrace:

2015-07-16 16:36:11.347 ERROR 5696 --- [nio-9001-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nest
ed exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.intuit.developer.sampleapp.timetracking.BillPaymentResponseFromXML.getPBResponse(BillPaymentResponseFromXML.java:206)
        at com.intuit.developer.sampleapp.timetracking.handlers.BillPaymentEventHandler.handleAfterSave(BillPaymentEventHandler.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: 2015-07-08 14:59:40.202 ERROR 4984 --- [nio-9001-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nest ed exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null at com.intuit.developer.sampleapp.timetracking.domain.BillPaymentResponseFromXML.getPBResponse

Comment: Need a couple of more lines of stack trace to really understand why NPE is coming up? Have you @Autowired PBResponseRepository in the controller class?

Comment: I have fixed this in one spot I implemented it by removing consumes produces and headers.